# php after log in successfully, display username at the top of the page?

Tags: php, html

I was able to make a user register using php and sign in as well. What I am trying to do now is that if I login, it goes to index.html then add "welcome" + username at the top menu bar where the lists below is:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="mypage.html">My Page</a></li>
    <li><a href="register.php">Sign up</a></li>
    <li><a href="login.php">Sign in</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want "welcome"+username before "My Page" only when user login. Please help!

and is there any way I can change "sign in" to "log out" in the same index.html? do I have to create another html file that replaces "sign in" to "log out"?

Thank you!

Comment: use session store the user name in session variable display it in your page

Comment: Everything is possible.. where is .php? and your html code can't get value from php, so it should be `index.php` for easier work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the script that logs the user in, store the user's username and a value that indicates that the user is logged in to `$_SESSION` like this:

(Place this at the top of the file so that session management can work):

```
session_start();
```

Then after valdiating the user add their username and the boolean value to the session superglobal array:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = <USERNAME>;
$_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;
```

To make things work you need to rename your `index.html` file to `index.php` so that you can include `php` tags in it.

After you've done that you can conditionally render both the greeting message and an appropriate button (login / logout) like this:

Start by calling  `session_start` at the beginning of the file:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

Then do this to render the greeting message only if the user is logged in:

```
<?php if($_SESSION['loggedIn']): ?>
<span>Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And this to render a login or logout button:

```
<?php if($_SESSION['loggedIn']): ?>
<button>Log Out</button>
<?php else: ?>
<button>Log In</button>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks in advance!

Comment: Typo here: `$_SESSON`.